# IIS HTTP Redirection despite Sitecore installation

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, sitecore, http-redirect

I am trying to have my Sitecore installation (IIS7.5 + Sitecore 6.5) take a subdirectory and redirect to an external website. For example:

www.domain.com -> Sitecore installed website

www.domain.com/anotherSite -> Redirects to www.anothersite.com/index.php?q=somestuff

I'm not very familiar with IIS (more of an nginx/apache guy), but I tried setting up a virtual folder for "anotherSite" then setting up an HTTP Redirect from that virtual folder to the destination. The probelm with that is that apparently Sitecore jumps in and tries to handle it before the redirect gets a chance and throws a 404.

Is there a way to intercept that one path in IIS before Sitecore gets involved and point it to an external URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your web.config (or maybe a separate include file beneath `~/App_Data/Inlcudes`) and search for a setting with the key `IgnoreUrlPrefixes`.

You might add the name of your virtual directory there to prevent Sitecore from processing these requests:

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="...|/anotherSite" />
```